# In Rally SDK 1.32 DropDown option is not working properly in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, rally

Actually I'm trying to count the number of User Stories and its associated QA Task  (TaskType) for each projects based upon Release and Iteration filter. I'm able to achieve it using SDK 1.32., but Release and Iteration dropdown are not working properly in IE browser.

[image]

also please let me know whether it's advisable to upgrade current SDK version to 2.0 or is there any workaround to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="Name" content="Project Board" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.32/sdk.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ReleaseDependencies() {

            var rallyDataSource;
            var cardBoard;
            var releaseDropdown;
            var table;
            var header;
            var task_count = 0;
            var data = new Array();
            var taskData = new Array();
            var iterDropdown;

            function buildHeaders() {
                var tableConfig = {
                    sortingEnabled: false,
                    columnKeys: [
                        'module', 'totstories', 'totcompleted', 'totinprogress',
                        'totqa', 'totblocked'
                    ],
                    columnHeaders: [
                        'MODULE', 'STORIES', 'COMPLETED', 'IN-PROGRESS', 'QA TASKS', 'BLOCKED'
                    ],
                    columnWidths: ['16%', '16%', '16%', '16%', '16%', '16%']
                };
                table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(tableConfig);
            }

            function destroyTables() {
                if (table) {
                    table.destroy();
                }
            }

            function onReleaseSelected(releases, eventArgs) {
                if (iterDropdown) {
                    iterDropdown.destroy();
                    destroyTables();
                }
                var queryConfig = {
                    label: "Select Iteration "
                };
                iterDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.IterationDropdown(queryConfig, rallyDataSource);
                iterDropdown.display(document.getElementById("releaseDiv2"), onIterationSelected);
                releaseDropdown.addEventListener("onChange", display);
            }

            function onIterationSelected(releases, eventArgs) {
                if (table) {
                    table.destroy();
                }
                var queryConfig = {};
                findProjects();
                iterDropdown.addEventListener("onLoad", findProjects);
                iterDropdown.addEventListener("onChange", findProjects);

            }


            this.display = function() {
                destroyTables();
                rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('1283334',
                    '2013244650',
                    'false',
                    'true');

                rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.showPageTools(true);
                releaseDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.ReleaseDropdown({}, rallyDataSource);
                releaseDropdown.display(document.getElementById("releaseDiv"), onReleaseSelected);
            };

            function findProjects() {
                buildHeaders();
                var targetReleaseName = releaseDropdown.getSelectedName();
                var relCond = '(Release.Name = "_REL_TARGET_")'.replace('_REL_TARGET_', targetReleaseName);
                var targetIterationName = iterDropdown.getSelectedName();
                var iterCond = '(Iteration.Name = "_ITER_TARGET_")'.replace('_ITER_TARGET_', targetIterationName);
                var storyCriteria = '(' + relCond + ' AND ' + iterCond + ')';

                rallyDataSource.find({
                    key: "stories",
                    type: "hierarchicalrequirement",
                    query: storyCriteria,
                    fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,Project,Parent,ScheduleState,Tasks,TaskType'
                }, onProjectsRetrieved);
            }

            function onProjectsRetrieved(results) {

                var rowCount = 0;
                var proCount = 0;
                var proName;
                var stateCount = 0;
                var progCount = 0;
                var n;
                var fields;
                var fieldLength = 0;
                var queryConfigs;
                var task_count = 0;
                var blocked = 0;

                for (var j = 0; j < results.stories.length; j++) {
                    var abc = results.stories[j].Project.Name;
                    data.push(abc);
                    data.sort();
                }
                data = unique(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    table.setCell(rowCount, 'module', data[i]);
                    var pr = data[i];
                    rally.forEach(results.stories, function(proj) {
                        story = proj;
                        if (proj.Project.Name == pr) {
                            proCount++;
                            n = n + proj.Name + "~";
                            fields = n.split('~');
                            fieldLength = fields.length - 1;
                            proName = proj.Project.Name
                            if (proj.ScheduleState == "Completed") {
                                stateCount++;
                            } else if (proj.ScheduleState == "In-Progress") {
                                progCount++;
                            }
                            if (proj.blocked == true) {
                                blocked++;
                            }
                            for (var q = 0; q < story.Tasks.length; q++) {
                                if (story.Tasks.length > 0) { //if(pr == story.Tasks[q].Project.Name)
                                    if (story.Tasks[q].TaskType == "QA") {
                                        task_count++;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    table.setCell(rowCount, 'totstories', fieldLength);
                    table.setCell(rowCount, 'totcompleted', stateCount);
                    table.setCell(rowCount, 'totinprogress', progCount);
                    table.setCell(rowCount, 'totqa', task_count);
                    table.setCell(rowCount, 'totblocked', blocked);
                    rowCount++;
                    proCount = 0;
                    stateCount = 0;
                    progCount = 0;
                    fieldLength = 0;
                    task_count = 0;
                    n = null;
                    if (blocked > 0) {
                        blocked = 0;
                    }

                }
                table.display(document.getElementById('projects'));
            }

            var unique = function(origArr) {
                var newArr = [],
                    origLen = origArr.length,
                    found,
                    x, y;
                for (x = 0; x < origLen; x++) {
                    found = undefined;
                    for (y = 0; y < newArr.length; y++) {
                        if (origArr[x] === newArr[y]) {
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!found) newArr.push(origArr[x]);
                }
                return newArr;
            }
        } //rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #header {
            margin-bottom: -22px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad() {
            var releaseDependencies = new ReleaseDependencies();
            releaseDependencies.display();
        }
        rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="releaseDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="releaseDiv2">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="projects">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

App SDK 1 is based on dojo 1.6, which officially supported IE 6, 7 and 8.  App SDK 1 has been deprecated for some time in favor of App SDK 2.0.  If you can upgrade that would be the ideal solution.  Otherwise, if you can give some more insight into what exactly is not working correctly and what specific IE version you're having trouble with maybe a workaround can be found.